# nearest ancestor node in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In my javascript experience, I found that is a very common task "searching the nearest ancestor of an element with some condition (tag name, class,...)". 
Can the parents() method of jquery do the job? The order of returned elements of parents() is predictable? Is top-to-bottom or bottom-to-top? 
For the moment I use this utility function:

```
function ancestor(elem, selector) {
  var $elem = $( elem ).parent();
  while( $elem.size() > 0 ) {
    if( $elem.is( selector ) ) 
    return $elem;
    else
       $elem = $elem.parent();
  }
  return null;
}
```

Can someone tell me if there is a clever way to do the job?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Edit**: Since jQuery 1.3, this has been built in as the [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) function. eg: `$('#foo').closest('.bar');`

---

yep - parents() traverses up the tree.

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <p id="c">
            <a id="d"></a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

`$('#d').parents("div:first");` will select div b.

Comment: Beware, John Resig plans to change .parents() to return elements in source order. See this bug filed by John himself after forum thread revolving around element order inside returned collections: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5994

Comment: Fortunately the jQuery team have since then closed this ticket with `wontfix`. So .parents() should be considered stable again.

Answer (score 17):

*Adding to @[nickf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9021/nickf)'s answer:*

jQuery 1.3 simplifyed this task with `closest`.

Given a DOM:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <p id="c">
            <a id="d"></a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can do:

```
$('#d').closest("div"); // returns [ div#b ]
```

> [[Closest](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest) returns a] set of
>   elements containing the closest parent
>   element that matches the specified
>   selector, the starting element
>   included.

Comment: The problem with .closest() is that it begins at the current element. From the [jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/closest/): "Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree." In general, this won't correctly answer the question because it is looking for ancestor elements only.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `closest`, because `parents` won't give you the result you expect if you're working with multiple elements. For instance, let's say you have this:

```
    <div id="0">
        <div id="1">test with <b>nested</b> divs.</div>
        <div id="2">another div.</div>
        <div id="3">yet <b>another</b> div.</div>
    </div>
```

and you want to add a class to the divs that have a `<b>` element as their immediate child (ie, 1 and 3). If you use `$('b').parents('div')`, you get divs 0, 1 and 3. If you use `$('b').parents('div:first')`, you only get div 1. To get 1 and 3, but not 0, you have to use `$('b').closest(elem)`.

Comment: The problem with .closest() is that it begins at the current element. From the [jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/closest/): "Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree." In general, this won't correctly answer the question because it is looking for ancestor elements only.

Answer (score 3):

closest() starts at current element, if the parent you are looking for has the same tag as current (eg. both are divs), use parent().closest()