# jquery get nearest parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [nearest ancestor node in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201314/nearest-ancestor-node-in-jquery)

html:

```
<div class="post">
    <h2><a href="#" title="">Pellentesque</a></h2>
    <p><a href="#" title="" class="more">More</a></p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.more').bind("hover", function(){
    $(this).parent('.post').hide() ;                      
});
```

on hover (.more) i want to hide the post, but it does nothing
if i use parents() instead it deletes ALL the .posts on the page

any help appreciated

Comment: closest does the same thing, deletes ALL .posts

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
$('.more').bind('hover',function()
{
    $(this).closest('.post').hide();
});
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/7RqDD/3/) is the working demo with single class.
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/7RqDD/4/) is the demo with multiple classes.

Comment: works on the demo, not on my site, something else must be going on

Comment: my bad guys, once it disappeared the next one took its place, so it deleted them instantly on a single hover i'll use a click event

Comment: Could you provide us the url to look at..

Answer (score 5):

Use jQuery.closest : http://api.jquery.com/closest/